# Create a form and have custom menu display based on user answers?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, javascript

I want to create a "User Guide" form that will allow users to answer questions and pick the categories that they are interested in viewing. After they pick their categories and answer the questions I would like it to redirect them to a page with a customized sidebar menu with the categories that they chose.

I am using Gravity Forms and it has let me have users pick categories they are interested in, however, I do not know how to have it connected with a sidebar menu customized to the answers they chose.

Any suggestions on a plugin or code I could use would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please provide a bit more detail. Do you already have an application environment?  Are you using a database on the back-end?  If so, which database? Do you have a plan to use cookies, sessions, database, something else, to pass values to the form?  Your answers to these questions could drive the potential answers.

Comment: @MikeBaxter I edited my question, please let me know if I still need to provide more detail. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to achieve your goal, use [WPForms](https://wpforms.com/)
This have a feature like [Multi page form](https://wpforms.com/features/multi-page-forms/?utm_source=wprepo&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=liteversion)

Comment: Thank you for the response. This looks like a helpful tool to do the first thing I need to do, however, how would it collect the data the users answer to display a sidebar menu based on their answers?

Comment: It seems your project need https://wpforms.com/addons/surveys-and-polls-addon/. Though I am not sure how to get this, but it looks like this.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is relatively easy, if you are familiar with Wordpress Theme modifications.  The following will assume you are at least comfortable with PHP, and hopefully **Wordpress Theme** modification.  If not, I can provide some additional links in subsequent updates to this answer ... just let me know.

**First step:**  Gravity Forms documentation has instructions for "Populating a Form Based On Another Submission".  Specifically, see their section on ["Setting up the first form to send data using confirmations"](https://docs.gravityforms.com/confirmation-query-string-populate-form/#setting-up-the-first-form-to-send-data-using-confirmations).  Use those instructions to pass your form field(s) to the desired the desired page(s) within your site.

**Next**: You will need to [modify your theme's page template(s)](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/wordpress-custom-page-templates/#template-files-in-wordpress) (or [create a child theme](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/)) to use those parameters for calculating which [custom nav menu](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/), [dynamic sidebar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Your_Sidebar), or other object to display.  Use `$_GET` to extract your parameters similar to the following:

```
if (isset($_GET['Param_A'])){
    switch ($_GET['Param_A']){
        case "User_Response_A":
            dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-sidebar-a' );
            break;
        case "User_Response_B":
            dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-sidebar-b' );
            break;
        case "User_Response_C":
            dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-sidebar-c' );
            break;
        default:
            dynamic_sidebar( 'custom-sidebar-WHATEVER' );
    } // end switch
} // end if
```

If you are comfortable with PHP, but not so comfortable with **Wordpress Theme** modifications, you could use an intermediary plugin like [**Insert PHP Code Snippet**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/) to add a modified version of the PHP I provided to any widget area.

If you want to get *really* tricky, you could use the `$_GET` value to set a cookie value, then use AJAX calls to change the sidebar/menu content in real-time. That is far more complex to setup.  Please submit another **Question**, if you wanted to go that route.